# how to display procedure output into java fields

Tags: java, arrays

i have a procedure which takes the username and outputs an auto identity ID as below. my target is to display the output from the procedure in a textfield as in my java code below when a button is pressed. so far the procedure works well but the output is  not displayed. please i kindly seek help.

```
private void jButton7ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
 {

        try {
            conn = inventconnect.ConnecrDb();
            stored_pro = conn.prepareCall("{call getentry(?)}");
            stored_pro.setString(1, this.txt_userrinfo.getText());
            stored_pro.execute();
            if (rs.next()) {
                String add1 = rs.getString("entry_id");
                jTextField1.setText(add1);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);

        }
    }
```

-

```
create procedure getentry
(
    @user_name nvarchar(50)
)
as 
begin
INSERT INTO entry_no(user_name,entry_type)
   VALUES(@user_name,'PO')
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() as entry_id
end
```

Comment: where does `rs` come from?

Comment: am actually new to java. i looking for a better where way to display the results of my procedure into a jtextfield. please help

Comment: my goal is to return the new just inserted ID and display it into the jtextfield